# Construction of a sequence of Random Variable with certain distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

So in my lecture notes I often encounter the statement: " There exist a prob. space on which are defined a sequence of independent RV's $(Y_n)_n$ with distrbution xy". Since this statement is used that often I am beginning to wonder if there is a specific standard technique to achieve this. I know this is true for normally distibuted RVs using the Rademacher functions. Is this also true for the Poisson distribution? Or even for any distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general result is the [Kolmogorov extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem). Essentially, you just need to specify finite-dimensional distributions in a way that doesn't contradict itself (these are the consistency conditions). The extension theorem then tells you that there exists a probability space and a random variable on this space that has the corresponding joint distribution.

In the special case of a countable amount of independent random variables, there is a simpler argumentation. The corresponding construction is that of the [product measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure).

Comment: Oh yes haven't thought about Kolmogorov!
Can you go into a bit more detail concerning the product measure? How would I use it to construct these?

Comment: Suppose you have a countable set of probability spaces $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), P_i)$ and the corresponding product space $(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}), P)$. Let $X_i$ be the map, that maps the $i$-th coordinate from the product measure to the real line (i.e. $X_2: (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) \mapsto x_2$ etc.). Then $X_i$ is a countable collection of independent random variables, where $X_i$ has distribution $P_i$.